# Can you set TARGETDIR to be a command line parameter?

Tags: wix, wix3.6

I have generated an msi which I'd like to be able to change the default installation directory of and I know that you can change WIX properties using command line parameters, but I can't seem to get this working for TARGETDIR like this:

> Installer.msi TARGETDIR=C:\

My Directory fragment is:

```
<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="SystemFolder"/>

      <!-- Desktop-->
      <Directory Id="DesktopFolder"/>

      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="DIR_Company" Name="Company Name">
          <Directory Id="DIR_SubDir" Name="Sub Directory" >
            <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="My Product">
              <Directory Id="DIR_ONE" Name="ONE"  />
              <Directory Id="DIR_TWO" Name="TWO" />
              <Directory Id="DIR_THREE" Name="THREE" />
            </Directory>
          </Directory>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>

  </Fragment>
```

Is this just not possible, or is it my syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect this is because you have predefined folders in your directory hierarchy, for instance, `ProgramFilesFolder`. Even though you set the `TARGETDIR` via the command line, it gets overwritten with the well-known location of your Program Files and all sub folders become relative.

As a workaround, you can set `INSTALLDIR` from the command line. If you give it a full path, it will overwrite the initial hierarchy you define in your WiX authoring.